# Oracle conditional column based on a single query field

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following pseudo case:

```
WITH SUB_Q1(
  ... COMPLEX CALCULATION  AS MYVALUE
),
SUB_Q2(
  ... COMPLEX CALCULATION  AS MYVALUE
)

SELECT 
    *
FROM MAIN_TABLE
```

And i need to add MYVALUE to the final query.
MYVALUE is conditional inside MAIN_TABLE, i.e. IF column XPTO is NULL i want the value from SUB_Q1 else the value from SUB_Q2

The only way i managed to get it to work was:

```
SELECT
   MAIN.*,
   DECODE (XPTO, NULL, SUB_Q1.MYVALUE, SUB_Q2.MYVALUE) AS MYVALUE,
FROM MAIN_TABLE
LEFT JOIN SUB_Q1 ON..
LEFT JOIN SUB_Q2 ON..
```

However this has a performance bottleneck as SUB_Q1 and SUB_Q2 complex calculations are being done when only one of them are really required per line.

Please advise.
Thanks

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What do the CTEs look like?  Is there aggregation?  Other tables?

Comment: try select main.*, case when xpto is null then (select .. from sub_q1 where ...) else (select ... from sub_q2 where ...) from main_table. But This is not warranted to be faster, as all depends on your queries.

Answer (score 0):

What about manipulating the JOIN condition using `XPTO` as following:

```
SELECT
   MAIN.*,
   DECODE (XPTO, NULL, SUB_Q1.MYVALUE, SUB_Q2.MYVALUE) AS MYVALUE,
FROM MAIN_TABLE
LEFT JOIN SUB_Q1 ON XPTO is null and ..
LEFT JOIN SUB_Q2 ON XPTO is not null and ..
```

Cheers!!